# Always get infinite recursion when saving OneToMany relation (already used @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference)

Tags: java

I'm writing a OneToMany relation using spring boot, one property can have many propertySale.

This is my property class:

```
@Data
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "Property")
public class Property {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="property", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = PropertySale.class)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<PropertySale> propertySales;
...
```

This is my propertySale class:

```
@Data
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "PropertySale")
public class PropertySale {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "property_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Property property;
...
```

I save propertySale like this:

```
@Override
    public ResponseEntity<PropertySale> savePropertySale(PropertySale propertySale) {
        Optional<Property> existPropertyOpt = this.propertyRepository.findById(propertySale.getProperty().getId());

        if(existPropertyOpt.isPresent()){
            Example<PropertySale> propertySaleExample =  Example.of(propertySale);
            Optional<PropertySale> existPropSale = this.propertySaleRepository.findOne(propertySaleExample);
            if(existPropSale.isPresent()){
                throw new PropertySaleAlreadyExistException();

            }else{
                Property existProperty = existPropertyOpt.get();
                propertySale.setProperty(existProperty);
                existProperty.addPropertySale(propertySale);
                this.propertyRepository.save(existProperty);
                return new ResponseEntity<>(propertySale, HttpStatus.CREATED);
            }

        }else{
            throw new PropertyNotFoundException(propertySale.getProperty().getId());
        }
    }
```

I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:459)
    at com.mikason.PropView.dataaccess.estateEntity.Property.hashCode(Property.java:12)
    at com.mikason.PropView.dataaccess.commercialEntity.PropertySale.hashCode(PropertySale.java:10)
    at java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:459)
    at com.mikason.PropView.dataaccess.estateEntity.Property.hashCode(Property.java:12)
    at com.mikason.PropView.dataaccess.commercialEntity.PropertySale.hashCode(PropertySale.java:10)
    at java.util.AbstractSet.hashCode(AbstractSet.java:126)
...
```

when I try to save a propertySale, could someone please tell me where I did wrong? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Short answer

Add [`@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude.html) annotation to the field `property` of `PropertySale`.

### Long answer

That happens because:

1. the [default implementation of `Set` used by Hibernate is `HashSet`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections), which is based on the hash code of its elements to store them, and...
2. Since you are using Lombok's `@Data` annotation, the hash code (and also equals and toString) implementations take all of the class fields into consideration. This means that `Property.hashCode()` calls `PropertySale.hashCode()` and vice-versa, causing the stack overflow error you are getting whenever any one of them is called (this is also going to happen if you call `.equals()` or `.toString()` with any of these two classes).

In order to fix this, you have some options available:

- Replace `@Data` with `@Getter` and `@Setter` on class `Property`. Since it is not used as an element inside a `Set`, it **probably** [doesn't need to override `hashCode`/`equals`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-model-pojo-equalshashcode), unlike `PropertySale`.
- Add `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` (and `@ToString.Exclude`) on field `PropertySale.property`, so `PropertySale.hashCode` won't call `Property.hashCode`.
- Write your own `hashCode`/`equals` implementations for `PropertySale` (in this case Lombok won't generate them) without calling `Property.hashCode` (you could still use `Property.id` though, for example).

### Bonus

As I mentioned the same problem may arise from `toString`, but the correction is almost the same as for `equals`/`hashCode`: [`ToString.Exclude`](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/ToString.Exclude.html) / avoiding `@Data` / custom implementation ...

You can also write unit tests to be sure that neither of these methods will throw a `StackOverflowError` when you run your application.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's the @data, the code works after I delete it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix:

Change your hashCode to exclude propertySale.

I got the same problem with OneToMany; then realize that the HashCode is making an infinite loop.

You only need to change the hashCode method to exclude it, then it will solve your problem.